# how to make sprite stop when colliding with an object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

i am making a game where an object is mostly flying and i would like some help as because i have a forward velocity when the sprite falls to the ground it caries on going forward however the rest of the code is still fine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BirdMovment : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public Vector3 flapVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f; 
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;

    bool didFlap = false;

    Animator animator;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }

    void Update (){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            didFlap = true; 
        }
    }

    // Physics update goes here
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Velocity.x = forwardSpeed;
        Velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (didFlap) {

            animator.SetTrigger("DoFlap");

            didFlap = false;
            if(Velocity.y < 0)
                Velocity.y = 0;

            Velocity += flapVelocity;
            }

        Velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (Velocity, maxSpeed);

        transform.position += Velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        float angle = 0;
        if(Velocity.y < 0)
        {
            angle = Mathf.Lerp(0 , -45 ,-Velocity.y / maxSpeed);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,angle);

    }
}
```

can you also tell me where i should place the code in order to make the forward velocity stop when my object hits the ground

Answer (score 0):

There are two quick ways to do this that I can think of off the top of my head.

The first way would be to add a multiple states to the object to change what it does during its update loop. For example if the object were to hit the ground you would set the state as "idle" (Or whatever you would like to call it). Based on the state the update loop would then call a specific function to update the objects velocity. In the case that the state is idle the update function may simply set the objects velocity to zero.

Another way to do it would be to simply set the forward speed to zero when you collide with the ground. Which isn't necessarily the best way but an option none the less.

Comment: can you please tell me how i would write the code and where to put it im kind of a beginner at making games

Comment: This is a good explanation of how collision masks work in unity. It should give you a basic example of how to set up the collisions in unity itself. The other link is a good example of how the callback for collisions work.  Good luck . https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, the simplest approach, I think, would be to add a Rigidbody2D (I'm assuming here that you making a 2D game) and let the physics engine do most of the work for us. You'll also need to add a 2D collider of some sort, in case your bird don't have one in the first place. I've modified your script to work with a physics engine, instead of directly manipulating transform position, try it and tell me did it worked :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Added this to make sure that you'll not forget to add a rigidbody and a collider to your game object
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D), typeof(CircleCollider2D))]
public class BirdMovment : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // I've changed it to Vector2, so it would be more comfortable to use with 2D physics
    public Vector2 flapVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f; 
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;

    bool didFlap = false;

    Animator animator;
    // I'm assuming here that your game is 2D and used 2D physics.
    // If not - just switch to the regular Rigidbody, only a few modifications will be needed, if at all
    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    // Here we will store the velocity achieved by flapping
    // It's calculating separately from the overall velocity and forwardSpeed for simplicity
    Vector2 userVelocity = Vector2.zero;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        myRigidbody = rigidbody2D;

    }

    void Update (){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            didFlap = true; 
        }
    }

    // Physics update goes here
    void FixedUpdate () {

        // We do not need to apply gravity, as the rigidbody does it for us (and it's doing so in more realistic form that can simply be achieved)
        //Velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // This is needed because you wan't to reset birds velocity on a flap, but at the same time want to retain realistic falling due to the gravity
        userVelocity.y = myRigidbody.velocity.y;

        if (didFlap) {

            animator.SetTrigger("DoFlap");

            didFlap = false;
            // Here we use user velocity instead of directly applying to rigidbody's velocity to simplify everything a little bit
            if (userVelocity.y < 0)
                userVelocity.y = 0;

            userVelocity += flapVelocity;
            }

        userVelocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(userVelocity, maxSpeed);

        // If we will directly change our transform avoiding the physics engine, everything will brake, so we don't want to do that :)
        //transform.position += Velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Instead we are setting the velocity of our rigidbody, so the physics engine will make all work for us
        myRigidbody.velocity = userVelocity;

        // Adding a forwardSpeed to our velocity
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(forwardSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

        // This part is mostly intact, only we're now using our rigidbody's velocity for calculations
        float angle = 0;
        if(myRigidbody.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            angle = Mathf.Lerp(0, -45, -myRigidbody.velocity.y / maxSpeed);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,angle);

    }
}
```